# We are currently investigating an issue impacting Source Type data for iOS 16.0 users. - Apple App Store Connect info banner

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

On one of my Flutter apps in the Apple App Store Connect web application, an information banner is displayed as follows:

[image: information banner on the Apple App Store Connect web application]

The text "We are currently investigating an issue impacting Source Type data for iOS 16.0 users." seems to indicate that some reports or analytics cannot be retrieved for a yet unknown reason.

I can see that there are some downloads still for the iOS 16.0 platform. I cannot see any other activity for this platform. Probably because there are not that many users yet.

**My question is whether this information may be an indication that an issue is affecting in any way the user experience when running on iOS 16.0 platform?**

I don't have any mobile device using this platform at the moment. So, I cannot test myself.

Comment: On my end actually to pass it to appstore i leave note about it for from version which might not working or something only indicate on the part